# Appropriate way to disable interrupts during runtime / while the application is running?

Tags: embedded, runtime, stm32, isr

I see there are two ways of disabling a specific ISR using the STM32 HAL.

To use the Timer Input Capture ISRs as an example, there is `HAL_TIM_IC_Start_IT()` and `HAL_TIM_IC_Stop()`, but there is also `HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(TIMx_IRQn)` and `HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIMx_IRQn)`.

I am tempted to use `HAL_TIM` API because these allow me to disable certain channels of a timer (ie. TIM_CHANNEL_1, TIM_CHANNEL_2, TIM_CHANNEL_3, etc.), where as using the `HAL_NVIC` API would disable all interrupts associated with TIMx.

Which API would be the most ideal to use when enabling/disabling interrupts on the fly / while the application is running?

Comment: How to you mean "ideal"? Speed, code size, side effects, ...? -- It also depends, do you want to delay the call of the ISR, or do you want to ignore the event during the disabled time? In the latter case you will miss it, in the former it is just postponed.

Comment: @thebusybee I just want to ignore it!

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends what you want to do:

If you disable the interrupt at the NVIC the flags still get set and maybe you want them to be set because you are going to poll for them.  Also maybe you would do this because you don't want to deconfigure the peripheral.

Alternatively if you want to stop watching one channel but not others then you need to do this at the channel level.